# Расшифровка шифротекста

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование

Есть фрагмент шифротекста, навскидку не смог понять какой это метод шифрования, но судя по всему обратимый. Подскажите, может кто знает такой метод?

Большой кусок шифротекста:
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

Малый кусок шифротекста:
RDkf/03eGu75X2gjfeojPKRy9TPBHBLhr6+H1vroCVn+NZAsWcV439YIQ2lu3Lwl

P.S. Заметил несколько повторяющихся фрагментов по типу RDkf/03

Comment: Не, ну обычно хоть какая-то сопутствующая информация должна быть. А то вдруг это телефонная книга города Иваново на японском языке?...

Comment: Обычный текст на русском языке, ничего необычного и без спецсимволов

Comment: Ну хоть какое-то "Юстас - Алексу" известно? :)

Comment: Скорее всего в сообщении фигурирует имя Анастасия (Настя)

Comment: Набор символов и особенно знак = в конце говорит о том, что для удобства представления на экране это закодировано в base64. но если его раскодировать то получаем нечто в бинарном виде. Но то что у двух совершенно разных по длине сообщений одинаковое начало действительно говорит о том, что используется достаточно простой метод, без лавинного эффекта. Так что предлагаю снять base64 и провести частотный анализ, для начала. А по результатам уже думать дальше

Comment: И да, под "простным методом" понимается только то, что нет сложной математики. А так то это вполне может оказаться xor с ключом длиной в полное сообщение ...

Comment: @Mike тоже думал на бейз, но при расшифровке выдает иероглифы, что меня немного смутило

Comment: ну так это шифровано, а потом base64 накрыто, для удобства представления

Comment: На глаз с частотным полный провал. встречаются практически все байты по небольшому кол-ву раз. Так что всякие там подстановочные, rot13 и т.п. отпадают. Это вполне может оказаться достаточно сильный шифр вроде AES только без CBC

Comment: "не смог понять какой это метод шифрования, но судя по всему обратимый" - на основании чего сделан такой вывод? :) в обеих строках только первые 8 байт одинаковые, остальное полный рандом, как заметил Mike, здесь может быть всё что угодно

Comment: @Zergatul на основании контекста, это из переписки и вряд ли туда кидают необратимые шифротексты, просто смысла нет

Comment: то что они обратимые не говорит о том, что это легко расшифровать. и не говорит о том, что можно выяснить алгоритм имея на руках всего пару сообщений.

Comment: @Mike есть еще пара сообщений

Comment: ну вот если сняв base64 какие нибудь закономерности найдете - тогда пишите. попробуйте частотный анализ N-грамм провести. но что то мне подсказывает, что распределение на любом N будет равномерным, а это означает, что шифр достаточно сильный и даже зная алгоритм без ключа вы его не откроете